# Can the views in VS Code's explorer sidebar be rearranged?

Tags: visual-studio-code, user-interface

I would like to switch the order of the 'Open Editors' view with the 'Folders' tab (i.e., 'Examples' in the screenshot) in VS code's explorer sidebar. Is there a way to accomplish this?

[image: The explorer sidebar with an arrow indicating the two tabs I want to switch]

I use VS code on Ubuntu 23.04 with [SwayWM](https://swaywm.org/) as my window manager. My VS code version is 1.86.2.

Things I tried:

- I tried drag and drop, which at first seemed to work, but as soon as I released my left mouse button the original order was restored.
- I have searched the user settings for "explorer" and looked at the configuration options. None seemed to control the tab order.
- I have tried to google the problem and looked for related stackoverflow posts.

Edit: This is my drag and drop attempt:

[image: Gif of me dragging and dropping the tab]

Comment: Drag and drop should work - jsut make sure you dropped it in the right place.  A solid black line under the `Example` view should appear to drop it underneath that view.

Comment: @Mark Thank you for your reply :-) I tried to drag and drop again and edited my post with a gif of the result. I tried multiple release positions, not just the one in the gif. Unfortunately, it does not work for me. Could you maybe tell me your reasoning why drag and drop should work? By chance, did you try it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[To aid in resolution of this issue]:

Here it is working for me.

[image]

Are you able to move the other views, like `Example` or `Outline`?  Can you move the `Open Editors` further down?

See this issue: [Drag and drop does not work in Wayland](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/156723).  I see mention of `Ububtu` and `Sway` drag and drop of various UI elements.

Comment: Thank you once again! Basically, no to all of your questions. No matter which tab I choose and no matter where I drag them they all jump back to their original position. I am on version 1.86.2.

Comment: I don't know of any setting that controls whether you can drag and drop views.  Can you DND views in the Panel?  If not, it probably has something to do with your OS and you may need to file an issue.

Comment: See the GitHub issue I mentioned - it looks like what you are experiencing.